# How to work in team with visual studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

net developer.Now a days we work on project with my team members.how to share a project so we can work on a single project and all changes applied on single project rather than we work on multiple projects and then we merge them please can anyone explain me how to do this

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control

Comment: its called source code control...

Answer (score 2):

In a team, one uses a [revision control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) tool, such as [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/), [Git](http://git-scm.com/), [TFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server), [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) or one of many others.